# How to get to values of each key in an object and evaluate it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am posting a request to my Node server and I am trying to check the value of each keys in the object to see if ALL keys are empty so that I can send an error message but nothing seems to work and I got some weird stuff showing up in the console.

This code is for debugging purpose :

```
export const verifyAddress = (address) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    console.log(address);
    const obj = <any>Object;
    const isAllEmpty = obj.values(address);
    console.log(isAllEmpty);

})};
```

Here is the response I get from the console.log, why does it seperate each letters ?

> {"address1":"","address2":"","city":"","province":"","country":"","postal_code":""}
>
> [ '{',
>     '"',
>     'a',
>     'd',
>     'd',
>     'r',
>     'e',
>     's',
>     's',
>     '1',....etc

Actual Code for what I am trying to achieve :

```
export const verifyAddress = (address) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    const obj = <any>Object;
    const isAllEmpty = obj.values(address).every(values => values === '');
    if(!isAllEmpty) {
      resolve()
    } else {
      reject('Form values are empty.')
    }
})};
```

Comment: Sounds like you're passing a JSON string, not an object. How are you calling `verifyAddress`?

Comment: Mega facepalm. How did I not notice. There goes 1 hour of my life ! LOL. Thanks!